# jQuery - loop selected option text for multiple selects

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to pull out the text from multiple select options, I've managed pull out the value for each with the following code, however when I use `.text()` I get all options text, rather than the one selected.

```
    $('#mySelects > .form-group select').each(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Here is a sample of the `HTML`:

```
    <div id="mySelects" class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
           <select name="select-1" id="select-1" class="form-control">
         <option selected="selected" value="0">Please Select</option>
         <option value="11700599">Test Value 1</option>
           </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
           <select name="select-2" id="select-2" class="form-control">
         <option selected="selected" value="0">Please Select</option>
         <option value="11700467">Test Value 2</option>
           </select>
   </div>
```

My current jQuery will return: `0, 0`
I want it to return: `"Please Select", "Please Select"` (or whatever text is selected)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `val()`, when called on the `<select>` element, will return the value attribute of the selected children `<option>`. However, when you call `.text()` on `$(this)`, you are fetching all text nodes within the entire `<select>` element itself. So, use this instead:

```
$('#mySelects > .form-group select').each(function(){
    var $optText = $(this).find('option:selected');
    alert($optText.text());
});
```

Here is a proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/7vvX7/